# Geometric Interpretation of Weak Derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

As we know, classic derivative $f'(x)$ of a function $f(x)$ can be interpreted as the rate of change of function $f$ in each point $x.$

How about weak derivative? Since it is defined through integral and therefore not relevant in sets of zero measure, what does it mean for a function to have weak derivative? What can the weak derivative of a function explains about its function?

Comment: In 1-D case you have FTC and hence there is not too much difference between weak and strong derivative. Maybe it will be more interesting to look at Muti-dimension functions

Comment: @wisher: So how would they relate in multi-dimensional1 case?

Comment: I saw your other post. As an undergraduate you may just need to work on one dimension. The mute-dimension is totally another story, it is not easy. But if you decide to learn more after your thesis, I suggest you to read H. Brezis book.

Answer (score 5):

If $g$ is the weak derivative of $f$, then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus holds: 
$$f(b)-f(a) = \int_a^b g(x)\,dx \tag{1}$$
Thus, even though $g$ may not succeed in expressing the *infinitesimal* rate of change of $f$ at every point, it captures the rate of change of $f$ on every *non-infinitesimal* scale.

For the purpose of estimating $f$, property $(1)$ is about as good as having classical derivative. For example, if $g$ happens to be square-integrable, we can write 
$$|f(b)-f(a)| \le \int_a^b |g(x)|\,dx \le\sqrt{b-a} \sqrt{\int_a^b |g(x)|^2\,dx}$$
and conclude that $f$ is Hölder continuous with exponent $1/2$.

For some other purposes, like locating the maximum or minimum of $f$, the weak derivative is not the right tool. For that one would use another generalized concept of derivative ([Subderivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative)).